# QuickSight Email reports at intra day frequency

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have created a dashboard which needs to be sent out via email report 3 times a day. How can I schedule the email report to be sent out multiple times a day?

Currently I only see the option to send it out at one time and I am not able to add more schedules to it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to schedule email report to be sent out multiple times a day. An ugly workaround that I can think of is to replicate this dashboard 3 times and set different schedules for each copy of the dashboard.